# Read a raw data file with missing values ​into sas

Tags: sas

I need to read a raw data file containing missing values ​​but am having trouble displaying it. the file contains the following values

```
ID Age Sex Date
A001 21 m 05/22/75
A002 32 m 06/15/63
A003 24 f 08/17/72
A004 .  03/27/69
A005 44 f 02/24/52
A007 39 m 11/11/57
A007 32 m 11/13/19
```

I've tried to write SAS code in every possible way. How could I write a code that makes me display the data file correctly?

```
data mydata;
    infile 
'percorso_del_tuo_file/nome_file.txt' 
dlm=' ' missover;
    length ID $4 Age 3 Sex $1 Date $8;
    input ID Age Sex Date;
run;
```

This is the code

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to **FIX the text file so it is consistent enough that it can be parsed**.

Either place the values in FIXED columns.

```
ID  Age Sex Date
A001 21 m 05/22/75
A004 .    03/27/69
A005 44 f 02/24/52
```

Or use a period for all missing values, including character values.

```
ID  Age Sex Date
A001 21 m 05/22/75
A004 . . 03/27/69
A005 44 f 02/24/52
```

Or use some other delimiter

```
ID|Age|Sex|Date
A001|21|m|05/22/75
A004|||03/27/69
A005|44|f|02/24/52
```

Make sure to quote any value that contains the delimiter.

```
ID/Age/Sex/Date
A001/21/m/"05/22/75"
A004///"03/27/69"
A005/44/f/"02/24/52"
```

While you are at it you should make sure to use 4 digits for YEAR values.

**IF YOU ARE LUCKY** the file only has spaces between the values and not anywhere else.  In that case you could use the DSD option.  That option is for a delimited file and it will treat adjacent delimiters as an indication of a missing value (rather than just padding added to make the columns look neater).  You should probably read the date column as date values instead of a character string.  It is not worth it to try and store numbers using less than the full 8 bytes needed for the 64-bit binary values SAS uses. So set the LENGTH to 8 for all numeric variables.

```
data mydata;
  infile 'percorso_del_tuo_file/nome_file.txt' dsd dlm=' ' truncover firstobs=2;
  length ID $4 Age 8 Sex $1 Date 8;
  input ID Age Sex Date :mmddyy. ;
  format date date9. ;
run;
```

If you really cannot fix the file then count how many values are on the line and then decide what you want to do in that situation.  For example you might assume that when there is a missing value it is the SEX value that is not there.

```
data mydata;
  infile 'percorso_del_tuo_file/nome_file.txt' truncover firstobs=2;
  length ID $4 Age 8 Sex $1 Date 8 ;
  input id age @;
  if countw(_infile_,' ') > 3 then input sex @;
  input date :mmddyy.;
  format date date9.;
run;
```

Comment: how can i fix the text file to be consistent in Sas? Because as command of the exercise it just says that I have to read the raw data file with missing values. How can I write the code so that it works? Is the code you wrote correct?

Comment: If (and it is a BIG if) there is exactly one space between the values just add the DSD option to the INFILE statement in your existing code.  That will treat two adjacent delimiters as meaning there is a missing value.  But normally files with spaces have multiple spaces (like in my first example) to line the columns up for humans to recognize.  Also make sure the file actually has spaces and not tab characters between the values.  If it is tabs then use DLM='09'x instead of DLM=' ' in your INFILE statement.

Comment: so what is the final code like? if I had to add the delimiters to make it more understandable in order to oeggeroo correctly how should I do?

Comment: There are many ways you could write code that can read a line with only four values. The final answer is one that works.  Try it and see.  To see if there are tabs use the LIST statement in a data step to dump the lines read to the log.  If there are non-printable characters like tabs then SAS will display the hexcode for every character in that line.

Comment: ok i got it, could you explain that to me if what does it do?

Comment: See example using DSD option in updated answer.